# Issues while implementing Paging in ASP.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

In my previous question i asked about the related issues while implementing paging and searching and updating number of page based on number of records found.I am new to MVC. I am retrieving records from database and based on that number of pages are calculated and this is working fine but the main issue is when i search a particular record from database then the number of page are not updated, they remain the same as for all records. Please help to solve it.  Thanks...

Product.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<SearchRecord.Models.tbl_product>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <title>Index</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#Button1').click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: 'Home/Index',
                    data: "{'searchString':'" + document.getElementById('searchString').value + "'}",
                    async: false,
                    success: function (response) {
                        $('#showData').html(response)
                    },
                    error: function () { alert("error"); }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    @Html.TextBox("searchString")
    <input type="button" value="filter" id="Button1" />
    <table id="showData">
        @{Html.RenderPartial("ViewProduct");}
    </table>

</body>
</html>

HomeController.cs

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using SearchRecord.Models;

namespace SearchRecord.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Home/
        AdventureWorkEntities db = new AdventureWorkEntities();
        const int pageSize = 10;

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Products(int page = 1)
        {
            var products = db.tbl_product.OrderBy(p => p.ProductId).Skip((page - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToList();
            ViewBag.CurrentPage = page;
            ViewBag.PageSize = pageSize;
            ViewBag.TotalPages = Math.Ceiling((double)db.tbl_product.Count() / pageSize);
            return View(products);
        }

  [HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string searchString)
{
    int page = 1;
    var query = db.tbl_product.OrderBy(p=>p.ProductName).Skip((page-1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToList().Where(p => p.ProductName.Contains(searchString));
    ViewBag.TotalPages = Math.Ceiling((double)db.tbl_product.Where(c => c.ProductName.Contains(searchString)).Count() / pageSize);

    return PartialView("Viewproduct", query.ToList());
}
    }
}
```

ViewProduct.cshtml (Partial View)

```
@model IEnumerable<SearchRecord.Models.tbl_product>
@{int i = 1;}
@foreach (var p in Model)
{
    <tr class="@(i++ % 2 == 0 ? "highlighted" : "")">
        <td>@p.ProductId
        </td>
        <td>@p.ProductName
        </td>
    </tr>
}
<div class="pagination">
    @for (int p = 1; p <= ViewBag.TotalPages; p++)
    {
        <a class="@(p == ViewBag.CurrentPage ? "current" : "")" href="@Url.Action("Products", "Home", new { page = p })">@p</a>
    }
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because of this line of code...

```
ViewBag.TotalPages = Math.Ceiling((double)db.tbl_product.Count() / pageSize);
```

You need to add the same "Where" clause you ueed to filter the results. This "where" clause should go right before the call to "Count"

#### Edit

you have this ...

```
ViewBag.TotalPages = Math.Ceiling((double)db.tbl_product.Count() / pageSize);
```

which is getting the count of all products. But you need to show the count of all products based on a specific search criteria, right? So, when you call "Count" you need to apply the filtering expression before you call "Count". Like this....

```
ViewBag.TotalPages = Math.Ceiling((double)db.tbl_product.Where(c => c.ProductName.Contains(searchString)).Count() / pageSize);
```

By the way, I'm talking about the code inside this action method....

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string searchString)
```

That should work

Comment: Should i use this query var query = db.tbl_product.Where(c => c.ProductName.Contains(searchString)).OrderBy(c=>c.ProductId).Skip((page-1)*pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToList(); below the ViewBag.TotalPages in the Product method because every time i run the program or search a specific data it returns all the page based on calculation

Comment: The result is same after changing the code.. can you please tell me in details where i am wrong...

Comment: I have edited my answer to include more details. Cheers

Comment: Now the number of pages are displayed properly but when i search for a particular record it display all records rather than 10 record at a time, and when i click on the link of a particular page it redirects to display all the links of page based on all records of a database.. Thanks for the above suggestions....

Comment: Ok, this is another question. In regards to this pagination issue, you are not doing any paging at all in your Index action method!!! What happened to the calls to Skip and Take?

Comment: I have updated the index method in the controller but i think the query is not working somewhere i am not correct...Please see my Index method

Comment: It returns Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: var query = db.tbl_product.OrderBy(p=>p.ProductName).Skip((page-1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToList().Where(p => p.ProductName.Contains(searchString));  I have made changes in this line...

Comment: Buddy, that's a complete different question now. Obviously, something is NULL. Debug it and do some work on your own!!!